# PHP Puppeteer setCookies()

Tags: php, web-scraping, cookies, puppeteer, setcookie

I'm using method setCookie to set login session on a website with Captcha, but method $page->cookies($url) doesn't return added cookie. How should cookies be set in PHP Puppeteer?

```
$page = $browser->newPage();

$page->setCookie([
    'name' => 'login',
    'value' => '***',
    'domain' => 'www.domain.com',
    'expires' => 0
]);

$page->setDefaultTimeout(20000);
$page->goto($url, ['waitUntil' => 'networkidle0']); // networkidle0

printf("url: %s\n", print_r($page->url(), true));
printf("cookies: %s\n", print_r($page->cookies($url), true));
```